# Expo-notifications Proguard

Tags: react-native, proguard, localnotification, expo-notifications

My project have implemented expo-notifications to handle with local notifications. It works fine in dev and prod. But if i turn on Proguard, the notifications dont appear.

In my rules in **proguard-rules.pro** i have:

```js
# expo-notifications

-keep class expo.modules.notifications.NotificationsScoper { *; }
```

That resolved my problem when buildind the release, but the notifications dont pop-up, in log appears:

```js
03-05 11:29:45.634 22515-22557/? E/expo-notifications: Could not save notification "a4c57834-d4ad-4613-bc18-afa8cadd228d": org.json.JSONObject.
```

Anybody can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved my problem.

I added the following line in **proguard-rules.pro**:

```js
-keep class expo.modules.** { *; }
```